# jquery error() calls showing up in firebug profile

Tags: jquery, firebug, profiler

I am working on an ASP.NET application that make a lot of jquery and javascript calls and trying to optimize the client side code as much as possible. (This web application is only designed to run on special hardware that has very low memory and processing power.)

The profiler in firebug is great for figuring out what calls are taking up the most time. I have already optimized a lot of my selectors and it is much faster.

However the profile shows a lot of jquery error() calls. In the attached image of the firebug profile window you can see it was called 52 times, accounting for 15.4 of the processing time.

Is that normal for jquery to call its error() like that? My code works flawlessy, and there are no error messages in the firefox error console. It seems like that is a significant performance hit. Is there anyway to get more info on what the errors are?

Thanks.

[Image](http://img267.yfrog.com/img267/1730/jqueryerror.jpg)

[alt text http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/1730/jqueryerror.jpg](http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/1730/jqueryerror.jpg)

EDIT: I am not using/calling the error() anywhere in my code. Those error() calls seem to executed by the jquery framework itself, based on what I can see by me inserting break points and stepping through the application line by line.

EDIT: I am using jquery version 1.4.2

Comment: Sorry it should be attached now, included link to the image as well since it is getting shrunk down by stackoverflow site.

Comment: do you actually call error() in your code somewhere? According to http://api.jquery.com/error/ this should be called i.e. when image fails to load.

Comment: I am not using/calling the error() anywhere in my code. Those error() calls seem to executed by the jquery framework itself, based on what I can see by me inserting break points and stepping through the application line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track this down you could use an un-minified version of jQuery and set a breakpoint in `error()` - that way you could see where it is being called from and you may be able to better understand what is going on.

Comment: I downloaded the un-minified version and it never hits the break point in error() and the error() no longer shows up in the profile. So it seems like a problem with the minified version and firebug. It looks to me like it is reporting another jquery function as the error()...